# Маршрутизация в WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, маршрутизация

подскажите как правильно сделать маршрутизацию для кастомной таксономии. Как сделать маршрутизацию для категорий таксономии я разобрался, но теперь нужно сделать маршрут для всех постов таксономии.

Регистрация кастомного поста:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_post_types' );
function register_post_types(){

register_post_type('standings', array(
    'label'  => null,
    'labels' => array(
        'name'               => 'Турнирная таблица', // основное название для типа записи
        'singular_name'      => 'Турнирная таблица', // название для одной записи этого типа
        'add_new'            => 'Добавить турнирную таблицу', // для добавления новой записи
        'add_new_item'       => 'Добавление турнирной таблицы', // заголовка у вновь создаваемой записи в админ-панели.
        'edit_item'          => 'Редактирование турнирной таблицы', // для редактирования типа записи
        'new_item'           => 'Новыая турнирная таблица', // текст новой записи
        'view_item'          => 'Смотреть турнирной таблицы', // для просмотра записи этого типа.
        'search_items'       => 'Искать турнирной таблицы', // для поиска по этим типам записи
        'not_found'          => 'Не найдено', // если в результате поиска ничего не было найдено
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'Не найдено в корзине', // если не было найдено в корзине
        'parent_item_colon'  => '', // для родителей (у древовидных типов)
        'menu_name'          => 'Турнирная таблица', // название меню
    ),
    'description'         => '',
    'public'              => true,
    'publicly_queryable'  => null, // зависит от public
    'exclude_from_search' => null, // зависит от public
    'show_ui'             => null, // зависит от public
    'show_in_menu'        => null, // показывать ли в меню адмнки
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => null, // по умолчанию значение show_in_menu
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => null, // зависит от public
    'show_in_rest'        => null, // добавить в REST API. C WP 4.7
    'rest_base'           => null, // $post_type. C WP 4.7
    'menu_position'       => 6,
    'menu_icon'           => null,
    //'capability_type'   => 'post',
    //'capabilities'      => 'post', // массив дополнительных прав для этого типа записи
    //'map_meta_cap'      => null, // Ставим true чтобы включить дефолтный обработчик специальных прав
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'supports'            => array('title','author'), // 'title','editor','author','thumbnail','excerpt','trackbacks','custom-fields','comments','revisions','page-attributes','post-formats'
    'taxonomies'          => array('standings_cat'),
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'rewrite'             => ['slug' => 'standings/%standings_cat%', 'with_front' => false ],
    'query_var'           => true,
) );

}
```

Ну регистрацию таксономии не буду показывать думаю в этом нет смысла. Слаг таксономии `standings_cat`

Теперь хуком меняю маршрут для категорий:

```
add_filter('post_type_link', 'standings_rout', 1, 2);

function standings_rout( $permalink, $post ){

if( strpos($permalink, '%standings_cat%') === FALSE )
    return $permalink;

// Получаем элементы таксы
$terms = get_the_terms($post, 'standings_cat');
// если есть элемент заменим холдер
if( ! is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms) && is_object($terms[0]) )
    $taxonomy_slug = $terms[0]->slug;
// элемента нет, а должен быть...
else
    $taxonomy_slug = 'no-products';

return str_replace('%standings_cat%', $taxonomy_slug, $permalink );
}
```

Получилось примерно так:

```
http://uh214936.ukrdomen.com/barsa/standings/djuflu-u-16/djuflu-u-16/
```

Здесь категория и название поста совпадают, это не баг просто так названо.

Где `djuflu-u-16` это название категории, term taxonomy. Вот ссылка для просмотра - http://uh214936.ukrdomen.com/barsa/standings/djuflu-u-16/djuflu-u-16/

Подскажите как мне сделать чтобы по маршруту http://uh214936.ukrdomen.com/barsa/standings/ отображались все посты из всех категорий в этой таксономии?

Comment: Я так предполагаю что нужно отказаться от того перенаправления хуком, на замену маршрута этой функцией - add_rewrite_rule()  https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_rewrite_rule

Answer (score 0):

Итак решение было под носом, при регистрации поста нужно было аргументу

`'has_archive' => true,`

вместо true задать интересующий нас слаг, например

`'has_archive' => 'standins',`
:)